# Switch back and forth between chroot jail and Host in the same terminal

Tags: shell-script, users, chroot

I have a created a chroot jail in my Ubuntu 14.04 machine using **schroot** and **debootstrap**.

Now I want to write a shell script that goes back and forth between my native environment and the chroot.

When I write the commands directly in a shell script it chokes the moment I switch to chroot.

For example:

```
...
sudo chroot /JAIL #folder to chroot
echo "Chrooted now"
...
```

I get switched to the chroot folder /JAIL however, I don't get the output in echo. It is only when I exit from the chroot to the Host, this output is printed. I inferred that this might have something to do with the user being changed when the when we enter chroot jail.

So, I tried the solutions mentioned in this question [How to switch back and forth between users quickly on a single terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71276/how-to-switch-back-and-forth-between-users-quickly-on-a-single-terminal)
I also read about [heredocs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) but couldn't get them to work.

Ideally I would like a shell script that has the flow as below:

1. chroot to jail
2. Do something there
3. Move back to Host
4. Do something here as well
5. Go back to chroot, and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply write the command after chroot:

```
chroot /jail /path/to/some/command <parameters>
```

2nd line of `man chroot`:

> NAME
>          chroot - run command or interactive shell with special root directory
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          chroot [OPTION] NEWROOT [COMMAND [ARG]...]

Comment: Yeah that's right, can't believe how I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the `echo` is executed after `sudo` exits has nothing to do with the user being changed.

Let's simplify the script:

```
...
cat
echo "After cat"
...
```

The `echo` command will be executed after `cat` is finished, as with every other sequence of commands that you write.

If you want some commands executed inside the chroot, you must pass them as parameters to the chroot.

If you have `/bin/bash` as your login shell, the command

```
chroot /dir
```

is equivalent to

```
chroot /dir /bin/bash -i
```

That means it starts an interactive shell. You can execute some commands by creating a shell script that is accessible in the chroot, or by specifying them on the command line

```
chroot /dir /path/to/script

chroot /dir /bin/bash -c 'some commands; more commands'
```

The `chroot` program will always wait for the command to finish, although both the script or the command line can start processes in the background.